# Query SQL and assign it to javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql

I have a .js file :

```
    $(function(){
                      var playItem = 0,
                  title=$('.jp-interface .jp-title'),
                  jPlayer=$("#jplayer"),
                  myPlayList = [
            {name:"BlackPlant",mp3:"audio/black_plant.mp3",ogg:"audio/black_plant.ogg"},
            {name:"Hidden",mp3:"audio/hidden.mp3",ogg:"audio/hidden.ogg"},
            {name:"The Separation",mp3:"audio/separation.mp3",ogg:"audio/separation.ogg"}
        ],      
        jPlay=function(idx){
            if(typeof idx==typeof 0)
                jPlayer.jPlayer("setMedia",myPlayList[idx]).jPlayer('play')
            if(typeof idx==typeof '')
                jPlayer.jPlayer("setMedia",myPlayList[playItem=idx=='next'?(++playItem<myPlayList.length?playItem:0):(--playItem>=0?playItem:myPlayList.length-1)]).jPlayer('play')                 
            title.text(myPlayList[playItem].name)
            Cufon.refresh()
        }

    jPlayer.jPlayer({
        ready: function() {
            jPlay(playItem)
        },
        ended:function(){
            jPlay('next')
        }
    })

    $(".jp-prev,.jp-next")
        .click( function() { 
            jPlay($(this).is('.jp-next')?'next':'prev')
            return false;
        })

});
```

-->
Database stored in sql server :

- `name` (`nvarchar`)
- `path` (`nvarchar`)

My music player in .aspx page using this script to play music. I want to query path and name in sql server and assign them to myPlayList .js file. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this script in your Aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function QueryDB() {
    PageMethods.GetServerData(OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
}

function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName)  {
    var name= result[0];//You will get your name here
    var path = result[1];//and your path here
}

function OnFailed(error, userContext, methodName) {
   alert(error);
}
</script>
```

you must also add

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

in your Aspx page

Now in your code behind you must add a page method like this

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string[] QueryDB()
{
/*   Query your database from here and pass the name and path where I am passing
 myName and myPath*/
    return new string[] { myName , myPath};
}
```